# Generalization of $E[f(X)g(X)] \geq E[f(X)]E[g(X)]$ for random vector $X$ and some increasing function $f,g$

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, inequality, expected-value

I was studying an inequality called Chebyshev's order inequality:
Let $X$ be any random variable and $f,g$ be continous function on $\mathbb{R}$. If both $f$ and $g$ are  monotoically increasing function, then
$$
\mathbb{E}[f(X)g(X)] \geq \mathbb{E}[f(X)]\mathbb{E}[g(X)].
$$

I am wondering if there is a multi-variaiate generalization? For example, take $X:=[X_0 \;\; X_1\;\; \dots X_{n-1}]^T \in \mathbb{R}^n$ be an random vector where $\{X_i: i=1,\dots,n\}$ has common mean and common higher moments.

I get stuck on describing a multi-variate function to be monotonically increasing properly...and would like to know if there is any reference to this inequality that I could study in this direction? Any comment is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: This reminds me of the [FKG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FKG_inequality) inequality, in particular [Chebyshev's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev%27s_sum_inequality) sum inequality.

Comment: @OliverDiaz Thanks for the great comment. Yes, FKG inequality is what I am looking for; e.g., https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0410155.pdf. However, to work on the multi-variate case, it requires an MTP2 distribution condition. I would need to study it a bit more...